# Can I use a Bootstrap class as a variable in a custom CSS rule?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

To make my website responsive, I was going to use media queries to change the text size, etc. The problem is that I use `bootstrap` to set the sizes for the text. I was wondering if there was a way to use the classes from the `bootstrap` in my CSS file.

For example, something like:

```css
.test {
    font-size: display-5; /* display-5 is a bootstrap defined size */
}
```

I originally thought I could do this using an `@import` rule but it didn't work.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: It's very ambiguous what you're trying to do. Are you asking whether you can *overwrite* bootstrap's CSS rules? (You sort-of can, sort-of can't in css: read up on "specificity") Are you importing two css files into your HTML? (Perfectly fine, but be aware their order matters - again: specificity.)

Comment: If `display-5` is a CSS variable (I'm not so familiar with bootstrap anymore), then you'd access it by going `font-size: var(--display-5);`

Comment: You cannot use Bootstrap classes names as values in your stylesheet. For example `.test {font-size: display-5;}` will not do anything. You can certainly alter the Bootstrap classes, however, I don't recommend it unless absolutely needed. Most times, you will find there is a class for exactly what you need. You should look into using `fs` from [Bootstrap 5 Text Utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/text/)

Comment: Use proper means of configuring Bootstrap rather than a pile of custom CSS. See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/text/#sass. No, you can't use a class in a CSS rule.

Comment: Okay, so we have some clarity now: please rephrase your question, `display-5` is not "a size" it's a *class*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i would do, is instead of relying on bootstrap, i would just do manual media queries instead like below

```html
<div>
  <p class="fontSizeClass">Your text here</p>
</div>
```

with the css being

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .fontSizeClass {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  .fontSizeClass {
    font-size: 80px;
  }
}
```

bootstrap has sizes listed here:

```
  sm `min-width > 576;`
  md `min-width > 768;`
  lg `min-width > 992;`
  xl `min-width > 1200`
 xxl `min-width > 1400`
```

Comment: This isn't necessary, but if it's done the breakpoints should at least align with [those Bootstrap uses](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/breakpoints/#available-breakpoints).